# Linking OpenBLAS include and lib search paths to CMake for OpenCV

Tags: c++, cmake, openblas, lapacke

I'm trying to somewhat follow this tutorial: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12957

Because I'm having the issue that

```
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
at: C:/Dev/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
at: C:/Dev/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:289 (message):
  No modules has been found: C:/Dev/opencv/Downloads/opencv_contrib-4.1.2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:371 (_glob_locations)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

but even after linking that in CMake I get errors.

I cloned OpenBLAS for their github and have it in the listed directory, and then I downloaded the lapacke.dll and moved it into the OpenBLAS folder that has the same filepath.

I do NOT however, see any include or lib folder in the OpenBLAS folder.

Comment: Did you build/install OpenBLAS? Why download the source for BLAS when they have [binary packages](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#binary-packages) you can just install?

Comment: @squareskittles: I think, usually the binary only provides only dll not the static library so if you need another library that need openblas for compilation, they will ask for static libraries. Also if you want to use static libraries in your projects, you will need to have static libraries which you can get if you'll build it from the source for your machine..

Comment: @NitinKumar [The package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/) contains the file CMakeLists.txt and Makefiles for different platforms. You can obtain the static library for OpenBLAS.